# How to add a custom colorer along the axis of a ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create an additional bar along the axis of a ggplot heatmap in R. For example, if I     have a data frame that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  a = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
  b = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
  y = c(-10, 3, 5, -2, 9, 1, -5, -2, 0)
)
df[c('a', 'b')] <- Map(paste0, c('a', 'b'), df[c('a', 'b')])
df

 a  b   y 
 a1 b1 -10
 a1 b2   3
 a1 b3   5
 a2 b1  -2
 a2 b2   9
 a2 b3   1
 a3 b1  -5
 a3 b2  -2
 a3 b3   0
```

And I create a heatmap like so:

```
gp <- ggplot(dfTest, aes(a, b)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = y)) 
gp
```

That produces the plot:
[image: heatmap]

But I want to add a coloured bar around the axis that represents some other value, say `z`:

```
z <- c(2, 4, 1, 7, 9, 3)
```

where, each entry in `z` would represent each entry in `df`... that is:

> a1 = 2, a2 = 4, a3 = 1 ... b1 = 7, b2 = 9, b3 = 3

For example, the resulting plot would look like this mock-up:
[image: heatmap with bar]

I was thinking of using `annotate` like in the example found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59627064/r-create-color-bar-to-label-yaxis-into-groups)... but I cant seem to get it to work for me... any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution isn't quite there but might get you close.

1. I think you'll want to use `ggnewscale` to use two different fill scales in one plot.
2. There's probably a better function for getting the marginal fills -- I'm manually plopping them in there but the y axis one isn't quite aligned right.
3. I'm not sure about the best way to make sure the two marginal plots use the same scale.

First, data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  a = paste0("a", c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)),
  b = paste0("b", c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)),
  c = c(-10, 3, 5, -2, 9, 1, -5, -2, 0)
)

z <- c(2, 4, 1, 7, 9, 3)
```

Then here we plot the tiles as you did, then use `ggnewscale::new_scale_fill` to initiate a new scale for the marginal plots.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggnewscale)

ggplot(df) + 
  geom_tile(aes(a, b, fill = c)) +
  scale_fill_continuous(guide = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  
  # everything after this will have new scale for fill
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_tile(data = tibble(a = paste0("a", 1:3),
                          d = z[1:3]),
            aes(x = a, y = 0.5, fill = d, height = 0.1)) +
  geom_tile(data = tibble(b = paste0("b", 1:3),
                          d = z[4:6]),
            aes(x = 0.45, y = b, fill = d, width = 0.1)) +
  
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "D", 
                       guide = guide_legend(order = 2))
```

[image]

Comment: very useful. Thank you